# Measuring Coherence Length for T1 and T2 values with IBMQ Experience

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, decoherence

So I'm currently working on a little program to measure how long the coherence time of a qubit is. Basically the idea is to initialise a qubit with a X or H gate then stick in a varying amount of identity gates (as I haven't been able to find any sort of delay gate/function) and just see how many identity gates it takes before the state decoheres to something unrecognisable (adding another H gate on the end for T2 measurement). So 2 questions off that:

1. Is there some sort of wait function or gate so I don't need to use Identity gates, as I know they will add more noise?
2. Is there a way to measure the time taken to run on the circuit. Either the time per shot or a time taken running all the shots?

I know that result().get_data() has a time to run but that is the total time, including set up and all the other stuff, not the time just spent on processing the circuit itself.

And yes I do also know that the last calibration values for T1 and T2 are easily available, this is just for my own interest in doing it.

Comment: As far as I know, the identity gate is what is used as a "wait gate". Also, you currently cannot view the time taken to run the circuit, but it is something that might be available in the future. [This tutorial](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/qiskit/ignis/relaxation_and_decoherence.ipynb) also outlines the process for doing what you want to do using Ignis. You might find helpful information on the process from this tutorial as well.